# How to put border round images in Outlook by default

Tags: vba, outlook

Here's something which has been annoying me for months, if not years.  When I paste an image into an Outlook email, it has no borders.  I can add these by right-clicking on the picture and choosing **Format Picture**, and there's probably a tool to do this too.  My question is: is there a way to ensure that all pasted images have borders?  If there was a CSS style sheet for Outlook, I could do this here; or maybe there's a setting somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I've got a Word 2010 macro that adds a border to images and center them:

```
Sub AddBlueBorderAndCenterImages()
    Dim oIshp As InlineShape
    Dim oshp As Shape

    For Each oIshp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes 'in line with text
        With oIshp.Borders
            .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
            .OutsideColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        End With
        oIshp.Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next oIshp

    For Each oshp In ActiveDocument.Shapes 'floating with text wraped around
        With oshp.Line
            .Style = msoLineSingle
            .Weight = 0.25
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        End With
    Next oshp

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'go back to top of doc
End Sub
```

I've tried adapting it to Outlook, the main thing is trying to get to Word's ActiveDocument from an Outlook item.

So here is the Outlook version (without any centering):

```
Sub AddBlueBorders()
    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set mail = insp.CurrentItem
        If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set wordActiveDocument = mail.GetInspector.WordEditor

            For Each oIshp In wordActiveDocument.InlineShapes 'in line with text
                With oIshp.Borders
                    .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    '.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt ' error: one of the values passed to this method or property is out of range
                    .OutsideColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                End With
            Next oIshp

            For Each oshp In wordActiveDocument.Shapes 'floating with text wraped around
                With oshp.Line
                    .Style = msoLineSingle
                    .Weight = 0.25
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                End With
            Next oshp

        'ElseIf insp.EditorType = olEditorHTML Then
        'Something else here, maybe using css?

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, this doesn't add a border to a company logo I have in my signature, maybe because it's in a footer or other document part.

This is not a default and it's not automatically adding borders to images as they are pasted/added to the email. You still have to associate this macro with a button or key shortcut. But hopefully it will help, even 4 months later.

Vaguely inspired from http://en.allexperts.com/q/Microsoft-Word-1058/Word-resize-pictures.htm

Comment: I don't seem able to accept this answer or award the bounty, which is a shame, as it works!  Presumably I must be using Word as my Outlook editor.  Thanks so much - you've changed my life!

Comment: This is great! Valid values for `OutsideLineWidth` which I noticed you commented out are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlinewidth (e.g., `wdLineWidth300pt`)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to provide a VBA macro (plus key short-cut to it).
Not sure how this works for image borders, but for *selected* in email text here is a simple example:

```
Sub ChangeSelectedExample()
    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set mail = insp.CurrentItem
        If insp.EditorType = olEditorHTML Then
            txt = ActiveInspector.HTMLEditor.Selection.CreateRange.Text
                  ActiveInspector.HTMLEditor.Selection.CreateRange.Text = txt & "<hello world 1>"
        ElseIf insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            txt = insp.CurrentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text
                  insp.CurrentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection = txt & "<hello world 2>"
        Else
            MsgBox ("not supported mail format")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("not supported view type")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried developing this idea, having added variables:

Dim insp As Inspector
Dim mail As MailItem
Dim txt As String

However, I can't see how to get at a picture.  Thanks for the idea - any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can't award the "bounty" (first time I've used it), as it doesn't solve the problem.  Maybe it will be applied automatically?  Not sure how the system works.